# solving a differential equation using substitution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

ok so I have to use the substitution x=e^t to change the following DE

$$x^2y''-3xy'+y = 1+ x^8 \ln^3 x +xe^{5x}$$

into a linear DE, I also have prove the needed chain rule, any help?? all I know in substitution is that y should be equal to a certain value then I find its derivative and plug in, is the case different here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=e^z$ then $y'(x)= \frac{dy}{dz}$$\frac{dz}{dx}$ gives $xy'(x)=\frac{dy}{dz}$. Similarly, $x^2y''(x)=\frac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\frac{dy}{dz}$.

- This reduces the given equation into $(D^2-D-3D+1)y=1+z^3.e^{8z}+e^z.e^{5e^z}$ where $D=\frac{d}{dz}$ .Can you take it from here?

Comment: yes thanks a lot

Comment: @ahrnad..my pleasure.